# includegraphics aspects ratio problem?

Tags: graphics, pdf

I'm using texmaker. I create my diagrams with excel via a pdf print. When I include this pdf to my document I scale this pdf to the textwidth. The result looks like that the aspect ratio wasn't respected. There is suddenly an ugly gap between the units on the y-axis.

That's the code including my pdf

```
\begin{diagram}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]
{xxx.pdf}
\captionof{diagram}{\label{dia:dia name}
\end{diagram}
```

Adding `keepaspectratio=true` to `includegraphics` doesn't help. It looks like latex doesn't respect the aspects ratio.

That's the diagram sniping with the wrong y axis. Why is there suddenly a blank space.....It doesn't appear in the original pdf generated from excel.

[image: diagramm wrong y-axis]
please help.

greetings

---

Its again me the thread starter.....at the blank space should be a µ.
Why can latex not display it anymore? I used in excel Latin Modern 12. With another font like arial latex can display the µ.

Comment: That looks like a fairly easy graph. Have you considered letting LaTeX make the diagram? I'd recommend [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/) for that. It has a very extensive manual to get you started, and there's also a lot of questions here regarding this package. Also, welome to our site!

Comment: Try `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1` in your preamble.

Comment: There is nothing in the image you show to suggest that the image has been scaled by different amounts in the x and y directions, the text is not distorted, why do you ask about keepaspectratio?

Comment: It seems that, in the end, your question completely changed.  Please consider changing the title and also the text of the question to immediately address the real problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Aren't you lacking a `}` in your code ?